# How to get value array of object using jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

i have problem to get all element in array of object using jquery...

i get this code from internet...

```
var id = 123;
var test = new Object();
test.Identification = id;
test.Group = "users";
test.Persons = new Array();

test.Persons.push({"FirstName":" AA ","LastName":"LA"});
test.Persons.push({"FirstName":" BB ","LastName":"LBB"});
test.Persons.push({"FirstName":" CC","LastName":"LC"});
test.Persons.push({"FirstName":" DD","LastName":"LD"});
```

how to get each of "FirstName" and "LastName" in Persons using JQuery??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use `$.each()` or `$.map()`, depending on what you want to do with it.

```
$.map(Persons, function(person) {
    return person.LastName + ", " + person.FirstName;
});
// -> ["Doe, John", "Appleseed, Marc", …]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `$.each()` to iterate through the array.

```
$.each(test.Persons, function(index){
    alert(this.FirstName);
    alert(this.LastName);
});
```

See a [**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/DDghb/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript syntax for array:

```
for(var i in test.Persons) {
    alert(test.Persons[i].FirstName + " " + test.Persons[i].LastName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery for that is a little overkill imho.

[Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```
test.Persons.forEach(function(person) {
  alert(person.FirstName + " " + person.LastName);
});
```

or simply by index:

```
alert(test.Persons[0].FirstName + " " + test.Persons[0].LastName);
```